From how many experts does LLM training using a mixture of experts (MoE) start slowing down compared to training LLMs without MoE?
I'm trying to find some information regarding the impact of the number of experts on LLM training. From how many experts does LLM training using a mixture of experts (MoE) start slowing down compared to training LLMs without MoE?

My research:
https://huggingface.co/blog/moe#how-does-scaling-the-number-of-experts-impact-pretraining states:

How does scaling the number of experts impact pretraining? More experts lead to improved sample efficiency and faster speedup, but these are diminishing gains (especially after 256 or 512), and more VRAM will be needed for inference. The properties studied in Switch Transformers at large scale were consistent at small scale, even with 2, 4, or 8 experts per layer.

which appears to contradict https://arxiv.org/pdf/2402.07871.pdf, which seems to say that the training speedup decreases when having 16  experts:



